# Issue with adding a Rate me button in the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

At first I coded the rate me button as part of the option menu and it worked nicely.

[image]

Now I'd like to put more attention to the rate me function. So I added an icon to RateMe menu main.xml. But when I run the app the rate me button is still in the menu and doesn't appear as a button on its own.

What am I missing?

This is my menu main.xml:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <item android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@mipmap/action_search"
            android:title="@string/settings"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            />

        <item android:id="@+id/RateMe"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_important"
            android:title="@string/RateMe"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            />

        <item android:id="@+id/about"
            android:icon="@mipmap/action_search"
            android:title="@string/about"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    </menu>
```

It shows correctly in studio:

[image]

Here is my mainactivity code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(id.settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    menu.findItem(id.about).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    menu.findItem(id.RateMe).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent i;
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case id.settings:
            i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case id.about:
            i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case id.RateMe:
            i = new Intent(this, RateMe.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my main layout file:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the rate me file (empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_rate_me"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bernard_zelmans.checksecurity.Activities.RateMe">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do same as other two menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` below`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

and replace all `android:showAsAction=` with `app:showAsAction=`

like :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@mipmap/action_search"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />

    <item android:id="@+id/RateMe"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_important"
        android:title="@string/RateMe"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

    <item android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@mipmap/action_search"
        android:title="@string/about"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

</menu>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you. Try to add `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` to your item.

```
<item android:id="@+id/RateMe"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_important"
      android:title="@string/RateMe"
      app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```